# How to make jackson deserialize objects with all list/map fields to unmodified list/map recursively?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

```
Class A {
    B b;
    List<B> list;
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map;
}

class B {
    List<Integer> list;
}
```

As an example, `A.list`, `A.map`, `A.list[x].list`, `A.map.values()`, `b.list` all should be unmodified list / map.

Comment: What do you mean with unmodified list/map? Can you show an example Json for the expected result?

Comment: I mean when a json String is deserialized to A ```a```, all list/map fields of ```a``` should be unmodified list/map. case is after I load configurations from file, I want the config object immutable.